# How to order by day?

Tags: date, orderby

Logically I am trying to order entry output by day only using EE native date picker. I want the system to ignore year and month and order only by day. The logic would be order_by="{customfield format='%d'}". This is not possible using native EE tags. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to sort by the day as opposed to the whole date?

Comment: It's for a list of birthdays. Year doesn't matter (older years float to the top). Month is a text field (so that a tag search can be used). I am trying to avoid creating a separate day field. I would like to use date picker.

Comment: Does this answer help you at all? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/243/how-can-i-order-by-a-custom-field-in-a-channel-entries-tag